# Catching ListView BeginScroll and EndScroll Events

Tags: delphi

Is any way to catch events when ListView begins vertical scrolling and ends it? 
First of all I tried to catch LVN_BEGINSCROLL and LVN_ENDSCROLL notifications, but the result not justified what I expected. Maybe I was wrong trying to handle these notifications (in parent form I handled WM_NOTIFY message and in it's handler I checked Msg.NMHdr.code). 
Also I tried to handle WM_VSCROLL message of my ListView and checked ScrollCode = SB_ENDSCROLL. But how to detect BeginScroll event? 
And when I scrolling ListView by mouse wheel WM_VSCROLL does not come. WM_MOUSEWHEEL messages comes instead. How to detect and handle events what I need with WM_MOUSEWHEEL message? Is it possible by checking delta, that is is high-order word in wParam of WM_MOUSEWHEEL message?

Or what can I do? 
Thanks.

Comment: VCL reflects notification messages from parent back to the control. So you should handle it in the control rather than the parent.

Comment: @David, just tried and form receives `WM_NOTIFY` with `LVN_BEGINSCROLL` and `LVN_ENDSCROLL` message codes.

Comment: @TLama And then reflects back to the control. So to fit in with VCL you are expected to handle these in the control.

Comment: What was the result that would justify your expectation? IOW how didn't it work?

Comment: @TLama: What David is not telling you is that a parent control redirects a `WM_NOTIFY` message to the appropriate child control as a new `CN_NOTIFY` message. So you can subclass the ListView and catch `CN_NOTIFY` instead of `WM_NOTIFY`. The `wParam` and `lParam` values will be the same.

Comment: @Remy, I know (actually, I always take message prototypes from the subclassed control, so I would notice that, I hope :-). But it was just a typo, I wanted to address Lumen with that comment.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that detail @Remy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LVN_BEGINSCROLL` and `LVN_ENDSCROLL` work fine for me when I try them, provided the app has XP themes enabled since they only work with ComCtrl32 v6.  But their timing is different than you are expecting, which is likely what is confusing you.

`WM_VSCROLL` by itself will work better for what you need, and it does not rely on ComCtl32 v6.  It will also handle mouse wheel scrolling, though the timing of wheel begin/end scroll notifications will act more like the `LVN_BEGINSCROLL` and `LVN_ENDSCROLL` notifications since a wheel has no idea when the next movement will occur, so each tick of the wheel is treated independantly.

When using `WM_VSCROLL`, you can use a boolean variable to keep track of the scrolling state so you can detect the BeginScroll, and then the message will notify you of EndScroll.

Try this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    IsScrolling: Boolean;
    PreviousWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure ListViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Commctrl;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PreviousWndProc := ListView1.WindowProc;
  ListView1.WindowProc := ListViewWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
{
type
  NMLVSCROLL = record
    hdr: NMHDR;
    dx: Integer;
    dy: Integer;
  end;
  LPNMLVSCROLL = ^NMLVSCROLL;
}
begin
  PreviousWndProc(Message);
  case Message.Msg of
    {
    CN_NOTIFY:
    begin
      case TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr^.code of
        LVN_BEGINSCROLL:
        begin
          if not IsScrolling then
          begin
            IsScrolling := True;
            // do something...
            // use LPNMLVSCROLL(Message.LParam) if needed...
          end;
        end;
        LVN_ENDSCROLL:
        begin
          if IsScrolling then
          begin
            IsScrolling := False;
            // do something...
            // use LPNMLVSCROLL(Message.LParam) if needed...
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    }
    WM_VSCROLL:
    begin
      if TWMVScroll(Message).ScrollCode = SB_ENDSCROLL then
      begin
        if IsScrolling then
        begin
          IsScrolling := False;
          // do something...
        end;
      end
      else if not IsScrolling then
      begin
        IsScrolling := True;
        // do something...
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```